# Пишу игру на pygame, приступил к реализации анимации путем целочисленного деления, ловлю ошибку

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame

код:

```
    # This is source-code for Battle on Tower game

import json
import math
import os  # Modules for develop
import random

import pygame as pg


class App:  # Main class for game
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.keys = {"rotate_left": pg.K_a,  # dictionaries with keys
                     "rotate_right": pg.K_d,
                     "shot": pg.K_SPACE,
                     "reload": pg.K_r}

        self.file_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)  # file load optimization
        self.img_dir = os.path.join(self.file_dir)
        self.json_config_dir = os.path.join(self.file_dir)

        with open(os.path.join(self.json_config_dir,
                               'file_paths.json')) as file_paths:  # load json config with file paths
            self.data = json.load(file_paths)

        self.background_img = pg.image.load(
            os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.data["images"]["background"]))  # loading background image and icon
        self.icon_img = pg.image.load(os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.data["images"]["icon"]))

        self.fps = 60  # main game params
        self.height, self.width = 1000, 600
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((self.height, self.width))
        pg.display.set_caption("Battle on Tower")
        pg.display.set_icon(self.icon_img)
        self.colors = [(0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255), (255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255), (255, 255, 0)]
        self.background_color = 135, 206, 235
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()

        self.tower_xp = 100  # common game object params
        self.ammo_count = 10
        self.arm_angle = 0
        self.ray_x = 120
        self.ray_y = 120
        self.length = 400
        self.ray_angle = 0
        self.is_shoot = True
        self.reloading = False
        self.game_over = False

        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()  # sprite groups
        self.bullets = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.enemies = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.sprites_init()

        self.run = True
        self.game_cycle()

    def game_cycle(self):  # game cycle
        while self.run:
            self.clock.tick(self.fps)
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    self.run = False
            self.update_screen()
            self.key_pressed()

    def draw_simple_objects(self):  # drawing simple objects
        ground_img = pg.image.load(os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.data["images"]["ground"]))

        image = pg.image.load(os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.data["images"]["player"][1]))
        new_img = pg.transform.rotate(image, self.arm_angle)
        rect = new_img.get_rect(center=image.get_rect(topleft=(115, 120)).center)

        self.screen.blit(new_img, rect)
        self.screen.blit(ground_img, (0, 500))
        pg.draw.circle(self.screen, self.colors[2],
                       (self.ray_x + self.length * math.cos(self.ray_angle * math.pi / 180),
                        self.ray_y + self.length * math.sin(self.ray_angle * math.pi / 180)), 8, 2)

    def key_pressed(self):
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[self.keys["rotate_right"]]:
            self.arm_angle -= 1
            self.ray_angle += 1
        if keys[self.keys["rotate_left"]]:
            self.arm_angle += 1
            self.ray_angle -= 1

    def sprites_init(self):  # initialisation single sprites
        global tower
        player = Player(x=120, y=120, colors=self.colors, screen=self.screen, keys=self.keys,
                        bullets=self.bullets, ammo_count=self.ammo_count, is_shoot=self.is_shoot,
                        reloading=self.reloading, data=self.data, img_dir=self.img_dir, ray_angle=self.ray_angle,
                        enemies=self.enemies)
        tower = Tower(x=50, y=150, colors=self.colors, tower_xp=self.tower_xp, enemies=self.enemies, data=self.data,
                      img_dir=self.img_dir)
        for i in range(5):
            enemy = EnemyOnGround(x=1000 + i * 300, y=430, colors=self.colors, bullets=self.bullets,
                                  enemies=self.enemies, all_sprites=self.all_sprites, data=self.data,
                                  img_dir=self.img_dir, anim_count=0)
            self.enemies.add(enemy)
        self.all_sprites.add(tower, player)

    def update_screen(self):  # update canvas for screen
        self.screen.blit(self.background_img, (-2, 0))
        if not self.game_over:  # if game lost, objects will be deleted
            self.all_sprites.update()
            self.bullets.update()
            self.enemies.update()
            self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
            self.bullets.draw(self.screen)
            self.enemies.draw(self.screen)
            self.draw_simple_objects()
        self.collision_with_tower()
        self.ammo_counter()
        self.lose()
        pg.display.update()

    def text_render(self, text, font, size, color, x, y):  # this method responding rendering text
        font = pg.font.SysFont(font, size)
        text = font.render(text, True, color)
        self.screen.blit(text, (x, y))

    def collision_with_tower(self):  # collision with tower
        global tower
        self.text_render(f'tower status: {str(round(self.tower_xp))}', "Arial", 40, self.colors[2], 0, 0)
        collide = pg.sprite.spritecollide(tower, self.enemies, False)
        if collide and self.tower_xp > 0:
            self.tower_xp -= 0.05
        if self.tower_xp <= 0:
            self.game_over = True
        if self.tower_xp < 100:
            self.tower_xp += 0.01

    def ammo_counter(self):  # quantity counter for ammo, if player shoots, ammo count reduced by one number.
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        self.text_render(f'Ammo: {str(round(self.ammo_count))}', "Arial", 40, self.colors[-2], 400, 0)
        if keys[self.keys["shot"]] and self.is_shoot and self.ammo_count > 0:
            self.ammo_count -= 1
            self.is_shoot = False
        if not keys[self.keys["shot"]]:
            self.is_shoot = True
        if keys[self.keys["reload"]]:
            self.reloading = True
        if self.reloading and self.ammo_count <= 10:
            self.ammo_count += 0.02
            self.text_render('Reloading...', 'Bahnschrift', 60, self.colors[-1], 400, 100)
        if not keys[self.keys["reload"]]:
            self.reloading = False

    def lose(self):  # if player lost, text "Game Over" will be displayed.
        if self.game_over:
            self.text_render('Game Over', 'Bahnschrift', 100, self.colors[2], 200, self.width // 2)


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):  # class for player
    def __init__(self, x, y, colors, screen, keys, bullets, ammo_count, is_shoot, reloading, data,
                 img_dir, ray_angle, enemies):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.colors = colors
        self.screen = screen
        self.keys = keys
        self.bullets = bullets
        self.ammo_count = ammo_count
        self.is_shoot = is_shoot
        self.reloading = reloading
        self.data = data
        self.img_dir = img_dir
        self.ray_angle = ray_angle
        self.enemies = enemies
        self.image = pg.image.load(os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.data["images"]["player"][0]))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.image.get_rect(topleft=(self.x, self.y)).center)
        self.attack = True  # variable which responsible for limit spawn bullets

    def update(self):  # this method responsible for update frame by frame
        self.key_pressed()
        self.ammo_counter_proc()

    def key_pressed(self):  # key pressing processing
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[self.keys["shot"]]:
            self.shot()
            self.attack = False
        if not keys[self.keys["shot"]]:
            self.attack = True
        if keys[self.keys["rotate_right"]]:
            self.ray_angle += 1
        if keys[self.keys["rotate_left"]]:
            self.ray_angle -= 1

    def shot(self):  # this method responsible for spawn bullets
        if self.attack and self.ammo_count > 0:
            bullet = Bullet(x=self.x, y=self.y, radius=5, colors=self.colors, speed=20, ray_angle=self.ray_angle,
                            keys=self.keys, enemies=self.enemies)
            self.bullets.add(bullet)

    def ammo_counter_proc(self):  # Reducing and reloading ammo
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[self.keys["shot"]] and self.is_shoot and self.ammo_count > 0:
            self.ammo_count -= 1
            self.is_shoot = False
        if not keys[self.keys["shot"]]:
            self.is_shoot = True
        if keys[self.keys["reload"]]:
            self.reloading = True
        if self.reloading and self.ammo_count <= 10:
            self.ammo_count += 0.02
        if not keys[self.keys["reload"]]:
            self.reloading = False


class Bullet(pg.sprite.Sprite):  # class for bullets
    def __init__(self, x, y, speed, radius, colors, ray_angle, keys, enemies):
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.speed = speed
        self.colors = colors
        self.radius = radius
        self.ray_angle = ray_angle
        self.keys = keys
        self.enemies = enemies
        self.image = pg.Surface((self.radius * 2, self.radius * 2))
        self.image.set_colorkey(self.colors[0], False)
        pg.draw.circle(self.image, self.colors[2], (self.radius, self.radius), self.radius)
        self.rect = pg.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.radius, self.radius)

    def update(self):
        self.force()
        self.key_pressed()
        # self.destroy()

    def key_pressed(self):
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[self.keys["rotate_right"]]:
            self.ray_angle += 1
        if keys[self.keys["rotate_left"]]:
            self.ray_angle -= 1

    def force(self):  # movement for ray direction
        self.rect.x += self.speed * math.cos(self.ray_angle * math.pi / 180)
        self.rect.y += self.speed * math.sin(self.ray_angle * math.pi / 180)

    def destroy(self):
        collide = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.enemies, False)
        if collide:
            self.kill()


class EnemyOnGround(pg.sprite.Sprite):  # class for enemies(on ground)
    def __init__(self, x, y, colors, bullets, enemies, all_sprites, data, img_dir, anim_count):
        super(EnemyOnGround, self).__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.colors = colors
        self.bullets = bullets
        self.enemies = enemies
        self.all_sprites = all_sprites
        self.data = data
        self.img_dir = img_dir
        self.anim_count = anim_count
        self.image = pg.image.load(os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.data["images"]["enemy"][0][0])).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.image.get_rect(topleft=(self.x, self.y)).center)
        self.isRunning = True
        self.isPunched = False
        self.isDead = False
        self.speed = random.randint(2, 5)

    def update(self):
        self.run()
        self.collision()
        self.animation()

    def run(self):
        if self.rect.x <= 150:  # movement
            self.isRunning = False
        if self.isRunning:
            self.rect.x -= self.speed

    def collision(self):  # collision with bullets and spawn for initial position
        collide1 = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.bullets, False)
        collide2 = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.all_sprites, False)
        if collide1 or self.rect.x < 0:
            self.isDead = True
        if self.isDead and self.anim_count >= 60:
            self.kill()
            list(map(lambda x: x.kill(), self.bullets))
            enemy = EnemyOnGround(x=2000, y=430, colors=self.colors, bullets=self.bullets,
                                  enemies=self.enemies, all_sprites=self.all_sprites, img_dir=self.img_dir,
                                  data=self.data, anim_count=0)
            self.enemies.add(enemy)
        if collide2:
            self.isPunched = True

    def animation(self):
        if self.anim_count >= 60:
            self.anim_count = 0
        if self.isRunning:
            self.image = pg.image.load(
                os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.data["images"]["enemy"][0][self.anim_count // 10])).convert_alpha()
            self.anim_count += 1
        if self.isPunched:
            self.image = pg.image.load(
                os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.data["images"]["enemy"][1][self.anim_count // 12])).convert_alpha()
            self.anim_count += 2
        if self.isDead:
            self.image = pg.image.load(
                os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.data["images"]["enemy"][2][self.anim_count // 20])).convert_alpha()
            self.anim_count += 1


class Tower(pg.sprite.Sprite):  # class for tower
    def __init__(self, x, y, colors, tower_xp, enemies, data, img_dir):
        super(Tower, self).__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.colors = colors
        self.tower_xp = tower_xp
        self.enemies = enemies
        self.data = data
        self.img_dir = img_dir
        self.image = pg.image.load(os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.data["images"]["tower"]))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.image.get_rect(topleft=(self.x, self.y)).center)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```

часть кода с ошибкой(баг после условия isDead)

```
        def animation(self):
        if self.anim_count >= 60:
            self.anim_count = 0
        if self.isRunning:
            self.image = pg.image.load(
                os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.data["images"]["enemy"][0][self.anim_count // 10])).convert_alpha()
            self.anim_count += 1
        if self.isPunched:
            self.image = pg.image.load(
                os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.data["images"]["enemy"][1][self.anim_count // 12])).convert_alpha()
            self.anim_count += 2
        if self.isDead:
            self.image = pg.image.load(
                os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.data["images"]["enemy"][2][self.anim_count // 20])).convert_alpha()
            self.anim_count += 1
```

часть кода где активируется анимация

```
        if self.isDead and self.anim_count >= 60:
            self.kill()
        list(map(lambda x: x.kill(), self.bullets))
```

Спустя какое-то количество срабатываний ловлю эту ошибку

```
  File "C:\Users\rtyse\Desktop\Battle on Tower\code.py", line 275, in update
  self.animation()
  File "C:\Users\rtyse\Desktop\Battle on Tower\code.py", line 311, in animation
  os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.data["images"]["enemy"][2][self.anim_count // 
  20])).convert_alpha()
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

json конфиг с путями:

```
  {
"images": {
  "icon" : "data/images/icon.png",
  "tower": "data/images/tower.png",
  "player": [
    "data/images/player.png",
    "data/images/arm.png"
  ],
  "ground": "data/images/ground.png",
  "background": "data/images/background.png",
  "enemy": [
    [
      "data/images/enemy/run/run1.png",
      "data/images/enemy/run/run2.png",
      "data/images/enemy/run/run3.png",
      "data/images/enemy/run/run4.png",
      "data/images/enemy/run/run5.png",
      "data/images/enemy/run/run6.png",
      "data/images/enemy/run/run7.png"
    ],
    [
      "data/images/enemy/punch/punch1.png",
      "data/images/enemy/punch/punch2.png",
      "data/images/enemy/punch/punch3.png",
      "data/images/enemy/punch/punch3.png",
      "data/images/enemy/punch/punch4.png",
      "data/images/enemy/punch/punch5.png"
    ],
    [
      "data/images/enemy/death/death1.png",
      "data/images/enemy/death/death2.png",
      "data/images/enemy/death/death3.png"
    ]
  ]
}
```

}

[Полная версия кода с файлами](https://github.com/coder6497/Battle-on-Tower/tree/main/Battle%20on%20Tower)

Comment: А почему вообще такой хитрый странный подсчёт? Сколько у вас вообще этих картинок в каждом из `self.data["images"]["enemy"]`?

Comment: посмотрите json файл по ссылке, там хранятся пути

Comment: Вот мне делать нечего. Вся нужная инфа по возможности должна быть в вопросе. Хотя бы выжимки из неё. Я понимаю, что там пути. Сколько их и почему вы так странно их берёте целочисленным делением?

Comment: я дополнил вопрос конфигом json, посмотрите

Comment: анимация с ошибкой находится в 3 списке словаря enemy

Answer (score 0):

Вы сбрасываете счётчик один раз, а потом можете несколько раз инкрементировать. Возможно, при очередном инкременте счётчик и выходит за рамки. Попробуйте выделить инкремент в отдельный метод, где будете сразу делать сброс при превышении. И вызывайте этот метод, когда нужно увеличить счётчик:

```
def anim_count_increment(self, n = 1):
    self.anim_count += n
    self.anim_count %= 60
```

Ну и вызов потом:

```
# вместо self.anim_count += 1
self.anim_count_increment()  # увеличение на 1

# вместо self.anim_count += 2
self.anim_count_increment(2) # увеличение на 2
```